# How to replace an entire paragraph in a file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, scripting

I want to change this:

```
...
 %%%23begin
 aaaaaaa \\
 bbbbbbb \\
 ccccccc \\
 %%%23end
 ...
```

to this

```
 ...
 %%%23begin
 xxxxxxxx \\
 yyyyyyyy \\
 zzzzzzzzz \\
 tttttttt \\
 %%%23end
 ...
```

the number of lines might change after editing.

using this function :

```
function editEntry(){
  local entryIndex="$1"
  local pattern='^%%%'$entryIndex'begin'
  d1=$(grep -n "$pattern" "$theBook" | cut -d: -f 1)
  d1=$((d1+1))
  local pattern='^%%%'$entryIndex'end'
  d2=$(grep -n "$pattern" "$theBook" | cut -d: -f 1)
  d2=$((d2-1))
  local text1=$(sed  -n "$d1,$d2"p "$theBook")
  echo "$text1" >| "$tmpfile"
  gedit "$tmpfile" && local text2=$(cat "$tmpfile" ) 
  sed -i "s@$text1@$text2@" "$theBook"
}
```

apparently sed does not change entire paragraphs , it only operates on lines

Comment: What change do you want to make? It looks like you want to operate on the lines between `23begin` and `23end`, is that right? Please [edit] your question and show us your desired output so we can understand what you need.

Comment: yes that's what I want and sed could not do the job

Comment: In the expected answer do you still want to be able to manually edit `$text1` into `$text2`? Which would mean that you are just looking for an easier way to extract the text between `23begin` and `23end`, right?

Comment: actually I can extract it, I want an easy way to replace it after I have edited it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scripting text edits is what `ed` is for:

```
ed file <<'SCRIPT'
/%%%23begin/+1,/%%%23end/-1d
/%%%23begin/a
 xxxxxxxx \\
 yyyyyyyy \\
 zzzzzzzzz \\
 tttttttt \\
.
wq
SCRIPT
```

First, delete the contents between (but not including) the markers, then append the desired text after the start marker. "Dot" ends input. Save and quit.

Comment: the function above is a part of a lager bash script that makes the file, and it contains arabic characters that's way I used gedit.

Comment: here is what I did based on your answer `      printf " /$pattern1/+1,/$pattern2/-1d \n /$pattern1/a $text2 \n . \n wq \n SCRIPT " | ed -s "$theBook" `
but it didn't work

Comment: If you want to use printf: `printf '%s\n' "/$pattern1/+1,/$pattern2/-1d" "/$pattern1/a" "$text2" . wq | ed -s "$theBook"` -- the "SCRIPT" is the heredoc terminator, not an ed command.